# 4.9.8 fr Weird behaviour, no media, many buttons unresponsive,

Tags: user-interface

Since a few days, I have incredible problems with a one WP blog. Long story short, a few examples: the media shows an empty page, but I can upload files, albeit with a strange interface, like old-style, and images are indeed uploaded.

In the pages/posts edit interface, I can't switch between visual and text, and I can't do anything with images - the buttons are like dead. If I make some changes in a post or page and switch to another page, WP doesn't reminds me to save my works, as if I haven't done anything. In the plugins' list, I can't select all extensions, I click the checkbox above the list and nothing happens. 
Everything is up-to-date.

So far, I have (unsuccessfully) tried to disable all plugins and my theme, up the memory to 256M, up the php from 7.0 to 7.2 and made a complete manual update via FTP (twice!).

It is on a dedicated server, with half a dozen other such WP blogs that don't show any problem.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

In the console, Chrome gave me an error related to MacAfee (sorry, I lost it, I copied on Wordpress' forum but I cleared the caches before sending it, and their system then flushed my message and asked me to reloggin).

Anyway, it was about a Query String and I remembered that I had a configuration about that on the CDN (StackPath), that is, to ignore them. I changed that, cleared the browsers’ caches and the problem on the blog disappeared. In a nutshell.

Problem solved!